# Laravel How to solve Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: laravel, cors, laravel-7

I want to read a pdf file though the api, but it gives me this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

after I tried Ammar answer, the error message changes to

```
Access to fetch the resource from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

this is my cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'=> '*',

    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Origin, Content-Type',

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => false,

    'max_age' => false,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Did you do `protected $middleware = [ \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,];` in the Kernel?

Comment: yes, it is the first one there

Answer (score 0):

I think the PDF file is in the `public` folder.
So you need to change this line:

```
    'paths' => ['api/*'],
```

To be like this:

```
    'paths' => ['*'],
```

Because the public folder path is not prefixed by `api` prefix group.

If that didn't work. Maybe laravel is not applying the CORS related HTTP headers to the response of the file. So you need to configure Apache or Nginx. Check out this issue:

https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/issues/163

---

## Update

Try to add this configuration to your webserver:

```
<Directory /path/to/your/public/folder/>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

Comment: thanks so much, I will try it now. But if I change it will that be "*" will that be considered a treat or it is ok to make it expose everthing.

Comment: It's not a treat if you are using laravel only to create an API. But it's not recommended if you have a normal web application you are running on the same laravel instance.
For that case, Configuring the webserver is a better way to achieve that.

Comment: I have the admin panel on the same laravel project

Comment: it didn't work it returns a new message, I will update the question with the new error

Comment: In what file should I put that in

Comment: It should be written in .htaccess
That will only work if you are using Apache server. It won't work for Nginx

Comment: sorry for my late reply,
I have added it to .htaccess file and I got 500 internal error. my ,htaccess is in my public folder and I have added the path to it using the output of pwd command